# Vaadin Grid disable in memory sorting for web component

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am using vaadin grid via stenciljs. The problem with the code below is that it does in-memory sorting first, and then eventually things get updated when the correct result is returned from the server.

```
<vaadin-grid-sort-column
     path={id}
     on-direction-changed={(e: CustomEvent) => {
         if (e.detail.value === "asc") {
           // go to server for sorting
         }
     }}
/>
```

I see the Java version can disable in-memory sorting, but I cannot find this in the web components version. Any suggestions?